# Problem with tagged template strings and closure

Tags: javascript, closures, template-strings

`Symbol.toPrimitive` method, invoked within tagged template literal loses access to the closure.

To reproduce, simply paste the provided code snippet in dev console, run it with and without tag-function. Any relevant articles are highly appreciated.

P.S. I would also appreciate if you give me an idea how and where to debug js code (including node.js). I'm interested in lexical environment, execution context and call stack.

```js
const isEmptyString = /^\s*$/;

class Thread {
  constructor() {
    this.scope = {
      current: '/test|0::0'
    };

    this.context = {
      current: '/test|0'
    };

    this.html = (strings, ...interpolations) => {
      var output = '';
      var prevMode = this._mode;

      this._mode = 'html';

      var {
        length
      } = interpolations;
      output += strings[0]

      for (let i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        output += String(interpolations[i]) + strings[i + 1];
      }

      this._mode = prevMode;
      return output;
    };
  }


  get id() {
    var fragment;

    const scope = this.scope.current;
    const context = this.context.current;

    return Object.defineProperties(function self(newFragment) {
      fragment = newFragment;
      return self;
    }, {
      scope: {
        get() {
          return scope
        }
      },
      context: {
        get() {
          return context
        }
      },
      fragment: {
        get() {
          return fragment
        }
      },

      [Symbol.toPrimitive]: {
        value: hint => {
          console.log('::', fragment, '::');
          const isFragmentDefined = !isEmptyString.test(fragment);

          const quote = isFragmentDefined ? '\'' : '';
          const suffix = isFragmentDefined ? `::${fragment}` : '';

          if (isFragmentDefined) fragment = '';

          switch (true) {
            case this._mode === 'html':
              return `node=${quote}${scope}${suffix}${quote}`;
            case this._mode === 'css':
              return `${context}${suffix}`.replace(invalidCSS, char => `\\${char}`);

            default:
              return `${scope}${suffix}`;
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
}

let thread = new Thread();



async function article() {
  let {
    id,
    html
  } = thread;

  let links = html `
    <ul>
      <li ${id('C-first-id')}></li>
      <li ${id('C-second-id')}></li>
      <li ${id('C-third-id')}></li>
      <li ${id('C-fourth-id')}></li>
    </ul>
  `;

  return html `
    <article>
      <h1 ${id('B-first-id')}>Some header</h1>
      <p ${id('B-second-id')}>Lorem ipsum...</p>
      <p ${id('B-third-id')}>Lorem ipsum...</p>
      <p ${id('B-fourth-id')}>Lorem ipsum...</p>

      <section>
        ${links}
      </section>
    </article>
  `;
}

async function content() {
  let {
    id,
    html
  } = thread;

  return html `
    <main>
      <div>
        <h1 ${id('A-first-id')}>Last article</h1>
        
        
        <div>
          <a href='#' ${id('A-second-id')}>More articles like this</a>
          ${await article()}
          <a href='#' ${id('A-third-id')}>Something else...</a>
          <a href='#' ${id('A-fourth-id')}>Something else...</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  `;
}

content();
```

Comment: Can you explain what this is supposed to do and where it's going wrong when it loses access to the closure?

Comment: Basically, if not to go in details, I use tagged template literal to temporarily change the `_mode` property on `thread` instance. So the consequent stringification via `String(interpolations[i])` in `html` method can apply appropriate transformation to string.

Since `_mode` is a property of the instance, I had to bind the `html` function to the instance via arrow function.

The expected output should be identical to the output you can get if you remove tag-function at the provided example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understand what you mean.

---

*After some comments below the confusion about what "run it with and without tag-function" meant:*

```
let { id, html } = thread;

console.log("Without tag function", `${id("A-first-id")}${id("A-second-id")}${id("A-third-id")}`);
console.log("With tag function", html`${id("A-first-id")}${id("A-second-id")}${id("A-third-id")}`);
```

The result is:

```
Without tag function /test|0::0::A-first-id/test|0::0::A-second-id/test|0::0::A-third-id
With tag function node='/test|0::0::A-third-id'node=/test|0::0node=/test|0::0
```

The difference is that without the tag-function, it works as intended, and "A-first-id", "A-second-id", and "A-third-id" is present in the result. When using the tag-function, only "A-third-id" is present (and the format is also different).

The question is why "A-first-id" and "A-second-id" are lost when using it with the tag-function.

---

But I noticed that you overwrite fragment every time that you call `id`, and the code in `Symbol.toPrimitive` is called at a later time. That is why you only get the last string `"[ABC]-fourth-id"` and you clear the fragment with `if (isFragmentDefined) fragment = '';`

```js
"use strict";

class Thread {
  constructor() {
    this.html = (strings, ...interpolations) => {
      var output = '';
      var {
        length
      } = interpolations;
      output += strings[0]

      for (let i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        output += String(interpolations[i]) + strings[i + 1];
      }

      return output;
    };
  }


  get id() {
    var fragment;

    return Object.defineProperties(function self(newFragment) {
      console.log("fragment new '%s' old '%s'", newFragment, fragment);
      fragment = newFragment; // overwrite fragment
      return self;
    }, {
      [Symbol.toPrimitive]: {
        value: hint => {
          // this is called later, fragment is the last value
          console.log("toPrimitive", fragment);
          return fragment;
        }
      }
    });
  }
}

let thread = new Thread();

async function content() {
  let {
    id,
    html
  } = thread;

  return html `
    ${id('A-first-id')}
    ${id('A-second-id')}
    ${id('A-third-id')}
    ${id('A-fourth-id')}
  `;
}

content().then(x => console.log(x));
```

Run the code above and you get:

```
fragment new 'A-first-id' old 'undefined'
fragment new 'A-second-id' old 'A-first-id'
fragment new 'A-third-id' old 'A-second-id'
fragment new 'A-fourth-id' old 'A-third-id'
toPrimitive A-fourth-id
toPrimitive A-fourth-id
toPrimitive A-fourth-id
toPrimitive A-fourth-id

  A-fourth-id
  A-fourth-id
  A-fourth-id
  A-fourth-id
```

So first the code in `id` is called for EVERY occurrence in your string, overwriting `fragment` every time. After that, `toPrimitive` is called, and it only has the last fragment set: `"A-fourth-id"`.

I'm pretty sure that this wasn't what you wanted.

I think that you wanted:

```
fragment new 'A-first-id' old 'undefined'
fragment new 'A-second-id' old 'A-first-id'
fragment new 'A-third-id' old 'A-second-id'
fragment new 'A-fourth-id' old 'A-third-id'
toPrimitive A-first-id
toPrimitive A-second-id
toPrimitive A-third-id
toPrimitive A-fourth-id

  A-first-id
  A-second-id
  A-third-id
  A-fourth-id
```

**And the real bug is**...

When I was looking at the code again and tried to explain why fragment was overwritten it hit me: you define `id` as a getter. So when you do:

```
let { id, html } = thread;
```

you are actually calling the code in `id`, and you get the function. So every time you use `id` in your string, it uses the same function with the same fragment.

The solution? Refactor your code so that `id` isn't a getter.

When you are using deconstructing of functions from an object, the function no longer knows the context. You can fix that, by binding the function in the constructor:

```
class MyClass {
  constructor() {


    // Bind this to some functions
    for (const name of ['one', 'two'])
      this[name] = this[name].bind(this);
  }
  one(value) {
    return this.two(value).toString(16);
  }
  two(value) {
    return value * 2;
  }
}

const my = new MyClass();
const {one, two} = my;
console.log(one(1000)); // Works since `one` was bound in the constructor
```

**And for debugging:**

- Browser: In Google Chrome, press F12, choose the source-tab. You can set breakpoints. [Chrome example](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript)
- Node: See [node example](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/)

**Update**

Tag-functions for template strings is just syntactic sugar for passing arguments to a function.

```
let { id, html } = thread;

// A tag function is just syntactic sugar:
html`${id("A-first-id")}${id("A-second-id")}${id("A-third-id")}`;

// for this:    
html(["", "", "", ""], id("A-first-id"), id("A-second-id"), id("A-third-id"));
```

Without the syntactic sugar it is obvious that you overwrite the fragment each time that you call id, and only the last value will be used when converted to a primitive value.

When you don't use the tag-function, each value is converted to the primitive value at each place in the template string. But when you use it with a tag-function, you get each value as a parameter to your tag-function, and the conversion to the primitive value dosen't happen until you convert it in the tag function. Therefore you only get the last value of your fragment.

Comment: Yes, indeed, `id('fragment')` calls are executed before tagged template string gets a chance to stringify the id, so I end up with the last id. BUT. It works just fine with regular template literal (`id|id('fragment')` are executed and stringified sequentially).

Comment: @Raised It would be so much easier to help you if you show the code "that works".

Comment: For example, if you change `<li ${id("C-first-id")}></li>` to `<li ${thread.id("C-first-id")}></li>` it also works, since that will call the getter for every string. Your bug is because `Thread.id` is a getter. Doing `let { id } = thread;` and then using `id` **is not the same** as using `thread.id`.

Comment: Simply remove `html`  before the template literal literal and you have the code that works.

Id is a getter intentionally.

Comment: Ah, so that is what you meant! Without the tag-function it works because each id is executed and transformed to the primitive value sequentially. When you do it with the tag function, it is just syntactic sugar to call a function. The values are transformed at a later time, therefore all have the latest fragment, and your code dosen't work.

Comment: Well, yes. Sadly. I think the root of the problem is now spotted. Can anyone please change the title of the question to better reflect what was actually going on? I either can't or don't know how to do this.

Comment: What would you like it to be?

Comment: What is the rationale behind `id` being a getter?

Comment: Some title, that reflects the fact that tagged template string literal is just a syntax sugar for a function call and has no low-level implementation ensuring sequential stringification of embedded values (which now seems quite obvious).

The id is an accessor because for implementation reasons I need a new function every time the property is accessed. Each function bakes the context in which it was created in a closure. But again, it's an implementation detail so I might need to explain what I am building to make this clear.

Comment: This is not Jeopardy! You should not give the answer :) I hope "Problem with tagged template strings and closure" works for you.

Comment: Yes. that's just fine. I don't mind answering but I suspect that going deep in-detail might be not worthwhile because if my ambitions to build my own framework won't freak you off, I still gonna need to spend some time describing architecture.